# Compare vectors of a doc and just a word

Tags: vector, nlp, word2vec, doc2vec

So, I have to compare vector of article and vector of single word. And I don't have any idea how to do it. Looks like that BERT and Doc2wec good work with long text, Word2vec works with single words. But how to compare long text with just a word?

Comment: Can you say more about why you want to compare a long text with a single word?

Comment: Sure) I would like to grouping websites by categories. I have a few categories (words) and I need to clustering list of websites. So, I decided that compare main content of main pages with categories is a good way.

Answer (score 4):

Some modes of the "Paragraph Vector" algorithm (aka `Doc2Vec` in libraries like Python `gensim`) will train both doc-vectors and word-vectors into the a shared coordinate space. (Specifically, any of the PV-DM `dm=1` modes, or the PV-DBOW mode `dm=0` if you enable the non-default interleaved word-vector training using `dbow_words=1`.)

In such a case, you **can** compare `Doc2Vec` doc-vectors with the co-trained word-vectors, with some utility. You can see some examples in the followup paper form the originators of the "Paragraph Vector" algorithm, "[Document Embedding with Paragraph Vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07998)".

However, beware that vectors for single words, having been trained in contexts of use, may not have vectors that match what we'd expect of those same words when intended as overarching categories. For example, `education` as used in many sentences wouldn't necessarily assume all facets/breadth that you might expect from `Education` as a category-header.

Such single word-vectors might work better than nothing, and perhaps help serve as a bootstrapping tool. But, it'd be better if you had expert-labelled examples of documents belonging to categories of interest. Then you you could also use more advanced classification algorithms, sensitive to categories that wouldn't necessarily be summarized-by (and in a tight sphere around) any single vector point. In real domains-of-interest, that'd likely do better than using single-word-vectors as category-anchors.

For any other non-`Doc2Vec` method of vectorizing a text, you could conceivably get a comparable vector for a single word by supplying a single-word text to the method. (Even in a `Doc2Vec` mode that doesn't create word-vectors, like pure PV-DBOW, you could use that model's out-of-training-text inference capability to infer a doc-vector for a single-word doc, for known words.)

But again, such simplified/degenerate single-word outputs might not well match the more general/textured categories you're seeking. The models are more typically used for larger contexts, and narrowing their output to a single word might reflect the peculiarities of that unnatural input case moreso than the usual import of the word in real context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BERT as is for words too. a single word is just a really short sentence. so, in theory, you should be able to use any sentence embedding as you like.

But if you don't have any supervised data, BERT is not the best option for you and there are better [options](https://github.com/Separius/awesome-sentence-embedding#encoders) out there!

I think it's best to first try [doc2vec](https://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/) and if it didn't work then switch to something else like SkipThoughts or USE.

Sorry that I can't help you much, it's completely task and data dependent and you should test different things.

Comment: Thanks, it is a useful info already) Can you please tell me what does it mean supervised data?

Comment: A bit about my solution. I'am going to clustering websites by categories. So, I think that compare main content of main pages with names of categories is a good way.

Comment: what I meant by supervised data, is a bunch of websites with their corresponding category (so you have a set of X(sentences in websites) and Y(category)). This way you can finetune BERT for your need and it should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your further comments that explain your problem a bit more, it sounds like you're actually trying to do Topic Modelling (categorizing documents by a given word is equivalent to labeling them with that topic). If this is what you're doing, I would recommend looking into LDA and variants of it (eg guidedLDA as an example).